# Alternative to Jtable plugin with PHP examples?

Tags: php, plugins, jquery-jtable

The jtable that could be found here http://jtable.org is useful, but it doesn't have important examples in PHP like cascade dropdownlist and etc. There are example mainly about ASP.NET.

So is there an alternative for this that also has the same CRUD functionality with PHP example for database with 7 000 records?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been using [Datatables](https://datatables.net/) and I'm very happy with it.

There are [many plugins](http://datatables.net/extras/) for this plugin as well.